# How to programatically add menu item to submenu that is created in XML by findViewById in Android Navigation View?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am developing an android app using Android Studio. I am working with navigation drawer and navigation view. I know how to programmatically add sub menu to navigation view. But there is a slight different for what I want to do.

Normally I add submenu like this to navigation view

```
 Menu menu = leftDrawer.getMenu();
SubMenu authSubMenu = menu.addSubMenu(22,22,96,"Settings");
 authSubMenu.add(22,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.logout_item_id),99,"Sign out");
```

But what I want is different. I want to add items to submenu that is already created in XML file.

I have XML this file for navigation drawer menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/left_m_item_trendy_hot"
            android:title="Trendy/Hot" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/left_m_item_male"
            android:title="Male" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/left_m_item_female"
            android:title="Female" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/left_m_item_designers"
            android:title="Designers/Community" />
    </group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/category_menu"
        android:title="Categories"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <menu>
            <item

                android:title="Sub item 1" />
            <item

                android:title="Sub item 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I want to do something like this

```
subMenu = findViewById(R.id.category_menu);
subMenu.add("Item 1");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To get to the `Submenu` you can do something like below, and then add the menu item to it.

Code as follows:

```
SubMenu subMenu = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.category_menu).getSubMenu();
subMenu.add("Sub item 3");
subMenu.add("Sub item 4");
```